# kde debian jessie wifi & wired simultaneously

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, wired

I am running debian jessie with kde desktop.  I have a wifi network with an attached printer and a wired network with internet access.  I need to use them simultaneously; however, if I enable wifi, the wired network loses connectivity.  The wired connection is configured in /etc/network/interfaces.  The wifi is managed using the kde NetworkManager frontend.

I have no idea how to proceed.. Can some help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the network-manager manage both interfaces: Comment out all lines regarding your wired connection in `/etc/network/interfaces` except `allow-hotplug eth0`.